# How do I use PostThreadMessage to close internet explorer from C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, messaging

I'm trying to start `iexplore.exe` let it run for 5 seconds and then close it again.

`iexplore` opens just fine however it doesn't close when I call the PostThreadMessage. 
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
CString IEPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE";//GetIEPath();
//IEPath += ' ' + url;
std::string strCommand((LPCTSTR)IEPath);
PROCESS_INFORMATION    procinfo;
STARTUPINFO    startupinfo;    
GetStartupInfo(&startupinfo);

CreateProcess(
        NULL,       
        (char *)strCommand.c_str(),// name of executable module
        NULL,           // lpProcessAttributes
        NULL,           // lpThreadAttributes
        false,          // handle inheritance option
        CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM,              // creation flags
        NULL,           // new environment block
        NULL,           // current directory name
        &startupinfo,    // startup information
        &procinfo        // process information
        );


Sleep(5000);
    ::PostThreadMessage(procinfo.dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0); //<---Dosent Close internet explorer!
```

Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Or is there better way what to do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can enumerate the windows on the desktop and send a WM_CLOSE to the IE window , it might work .. you can use the spy programme to get the window class of the IE window

Comment: I hoped to avoid the enumration of windows, since i got a handle to the process and the thread.

Answer (score 1):

What is the return value from the PostThreadMessage call? That might give a clue.

Comment: The return value is 1, so everything should be OK

Answer (score 1):

For me, this works perfect:

```
TerminateProcess(procinfo.hProcess, 0);
```

Comment: It works for me to, however i dont know how nice this method is, does it clean up?

Comment: No cleanup, bad idea. This will quite likely leak temporary files. That's worse than a memory leak; a persistent loss of HD capacity.

Comment: This kind of behavior is exactly why many Windows programs suck.

Comment: Good point John Dibling, fortunately nobody in the Unix environment ever feels the need to do a "kill -9" huh. Oh right, they do all the time.

Comment: if your program load DLLs whats happened ? whose gonna unload them properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending WM_CLOSE to the main (top-evel) window. That's equivalent to the normal Alt-F4 exit.

Comment: should i then enumerate the windows, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer specifically why PostThreadMessage didn't work. But, perhaps if you elaborate on why you want to do this, there is a better solution?

For example, if you just want to show a web page for 5 seconds, you can create and show your own window with an embedded Internet Explorer ActiveX control. You'll be also able to add a sink to detect when the web page is loaded in the ActiveX control, so that you start your 5-second counter only after the web page is loaded and displayed.

Comment: Here is what i would use it for. When the user push a button in my program ie.exe opens on a specific webpage. When the user logs off my system it should close ie,exe too. Also the second time a user pushes the button, the old ie.ee should close and a new one opens.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing an enumeration of the windows (As serval of you mentioned i should do)
I was inspired of http://simplesamples.info/Windows/EnumWindows.php.

Comment: The reason why it works is because it uses SendMessage() rather than XXXThreadMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PostThreadMessage(), which sends a message to a specific thread in the target process instead of the process' Windows Message Pump.  Use PostMessage() or SendMessage() instead, which place the message in the target process's Windows Message Pump -- which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, never use SendMessage() (basic win32 rule)
Don't use EnmWindows() (horrible)